# Probability question about drawing without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I tried solving this question but seem to keep making a mistake without noticing it, so please be gentle.

A box contains $b$ red balls, $2b$ white balls, and
$3b$ blue balls, where $b$ is a positive integer.  Three balls
are selected at random from the box.
If balls are drawn without replacement and $B$
denotes the event that "No two of the three drawn
balls are blue" then prove that $P(B)= 1/2$ for any value of $b$.

What I tried: since we are drawing without replacement, the required probability should be equal to

$$
3 \cdot P(B, \text{not }B, \text{not }B) + P(\text{not }B, \text{not }B, \text{not }B)
= \\ \qquad\qquad 3\cdot \frac{3b}{6b}\cdot \frac{3b-1}{6b-1}\cdot \frac{3b-2}{6b-2} + \frac{3b}{6b}\cdot \frac{3b}{6b-1}\cdot \frac{3b-1}{6b-1}.
$$

Which is different from the desired answer, so please help me find my mistake.

Comment: Your first expression is right, but you're making some mistakes in translating that to probabilities.  Initially there are $3b$ blue balls and $3b$ not-blue balls.  So $P(B, \neg B, \neg B)$ should be $3b/(6b)$ times $3b/(6b-1)$ times $(3b-1)/(6b-2)$.  And the probability of three not-$B$'s should be $3b/(6b)$ times $(3b-1)/(6b-1)$ times $(3b-2)/(6b-2)$.  Expanding and simplifying all that stuff should get you where you want to go.  But it doesn't really tell you *why* it's so... which is just symmetry: at most 1 blue ball is exactly as probable as at most 1 not-blue ball.

Comment: Oh thanks, i was stuck for an hour now.